# symfony2.3 performance tips on service, controller, controller as service

Tags: php, performance, symfony, service

What are the main differences, in term of performance between service, controller as a service or using a sort of auxiliary object to do the job?

more precisely for this scenario/use-case:

i've got an **API** on `mysite/api`, my question is:

Is it better to define a ***controller as service***, a ***service*** itself or using in "*classical way*" as a ***controller*** doing all the job with at least an auxiliary object (as a mini-lib) to do most of the job?

> auxiliary object I mean use an istance of a class, i suppose everytime the api is called, create the new object (not so good for performance I think).

thanks in advice for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any significant performance differences, and all three approaches are absolutely valid, it just matters on your use case.

Thing to note: Controllers are basically services, they are just container aware by default in Symfony (making them Service Locators). It doesn't matter whether controller is a Service, a ContainerAwareInterface object or some object you made, it **has** to be instantiated either way.

That said, controller is just one of probably hundreds (if not thousands) of objects that will be created on each request and time needed to instantiate it is really negligible.

Use whatever method suits you best.

#### Edit

Hell, symfony controllers aren't even ContainerAware by default, they are just made so in their examples since they always extends`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`. You can try to make a `Controller` class like so:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyBundle\Controller;

class MyCustomController
{
    public function myAction()
    {
        // do your thing here
    }
}
```

And it will work just fine.

Here is the Symfony code that instantiates controller: [ControllerResolver::createController](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php#L55)

Basically, it checks whether string matches 'Bundle' pattern or 'Service' pattern. If neither, it just treats it as 'ClassName::methodName', and one way or another: instantiates it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference which approach to use. But there are a lot of another questions - rest api routing, formats, documentation etc.
Use ready solution for rest-api [gimler/symfony-rest-edition](https://github.com/gimler/symfony-rest-edition)